# JSON error: Expecting ... got 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

What is the error in this JSON code?

```
{
  “status”: ”Completed”
}
```

> Error: Parse error on line 1: '{ “status”: ”Compl ^
>
> Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: this char (  ”  ) might causing the problem, try to use single cote( ' ) or double cote ( " )

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using two inverted quotes rather than a double quote, this works fine

```
JSON.parse( '{ "status": "Completed" }' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Put Your code here [online json parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Look at the **Quotes**

> Your Code

```
{ “status”: ”Completed” }
```

> Correct Code

```
{ "status": "Completed" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The char `”` is the problem. ASCII code for this is `8221`.

Use double inverted quotes and it will work just fine:

```
{ "status": "Completed" }
```

**Note** : These kind of error comes when we try to copy json from doc files or any other format files. Beware!